# Leap Motion: Volume Control jPlayer (need to create smooth incremental values?)

Tags: javascript, gesture, volume, jplayer, leap-motion

I am building a leap motion controlled music player and have come to a roadblock.

The volume, I want this to work on 'circle' gestures clockwise being volume up and anticlockwise being volume down, however I cannot work out how to get the 'right' values to set the volume to.

I am using jPlayer as the audio player, the volume is set like so: `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("volume", volumeValue);` volumeValue needing to be between 0 and 1

I have it working so if you rotate clockwise it sets the volume to 0.75 and if rotate left 0.25, however cant work out how to increase the volume incrementally with rotation.

To get the number of rotations, this function can be used `circleCount = gesture.progress.toFixed(2);`

Below is my code... (obviously I realise this doesn't do much atm)

```
if (gesture.type == 'circle') {

        gesture.pointable = frame.pointable(gesture.pointableIds[i]);

        if(gesture.state == 'start') {
            clockwise = true;
        } else if (gesture.state == 'update') {
            direction = gesture.pointable.direction;

            if(direction) {
                normal = gesture.normal;

                clockwise = Leap.vec3.dot(direction, normal) > 0;
                if(clockwise) {
                    if (gesture.progress.toFixed(2) > 1) {
                        //volume up
                          ("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("volume", 0.75);

                    }
                } else {
                    if (gesture.progress.toFixed(2) > 1) {
                        //volume down
                         ("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("volume", 0.25);

                    }
                }
            }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put:

```
gesture.progress.toFixed(2) > 1
```

That means the volume will only ever change after a complete circle. The progress value isn't an integer, though, it varies fairly smoothly as you make the circle. If you want one full circle to change the volume between the minimum and the maximum, you could use the progress value directly. If you wanted it to take, for example, 3 full turns to go from minimum to maximum value, divide progress by three.

[Edit] From your comment, it sounds like you want the circle progress to reach a threshold value and from there, it affects the volume. You could use something like:

```
var threshold = 1;
if (gesture.type == 'circle') {

    gesture.pointable = frame.pointable(gesture.pointableIds[i]);

    if(gesture.state == 'start') {
        clockwise = true;
    } else if (gesture.state == 'update') {
        direction = gesture.pointable.direction;
        var newVolume = 0;
        if(direction) {
            normal = gesture.normal;

            clockwise = Leap.vec3.dot(direction, normal) > 0;
            if(clockwise) {
                if (gesture.progress > threshold) {
                    //volume up
                    newVolume = gesture.progress - threshold;
                    if(newVolume > 1) newVolume = 1;  
                }
            } else {
                if (gesture.progress > threshold) {
                    //volume down
                    newVolume = 1 - (gesture.progress - threshold);
                    if(newVolume < 0) newVolume = 0;

                }
            }
        }
        ("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("volume", newVolume);

        }
    }
```

(I didn't test this, so look out for syntax errors).

Comment: Hi thanks for responding! the reason I added the IF statement was so that users did not inadvertently alter the volume whilst performing other gestures. The bit I am struggling with is making the progress value a usable integer as you say it currently isn't...

Comment: What is the range of values you need to input to the audio player? Why do you need progress to be an integer?

Comment: the audio player needs a value between 0 and 1 for the volume level i.e. 0.25 = 1/4 volume

Comment: Then you don't want an integer (which is a whole number without any decimal portion, i.e. 1,2,3, etc). I've edited the answer I gave with a possible solution.

Comment: Doh! Yes your right, clearly going mental with this project! I actually found a way to do it in the end but thank you for your answer! (pretty much exactly how I did it with a few slight differences)